# mySQL select from primary key and select from foreign key big O

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I havent found any real data about the big O of mySQL select queries from foreign and from primary keys. Here are two example queries:

```
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE primary_key = some_value
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE foreign_key = some_value
```

Whats the big O of those two queries?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`...

The `PRIMARY KEY` is 'clustered' with the data, so when `WHERE primary_key = some_value` drills down the BTree to the leaf node, it finds the entire record there.

A secondary index (I am assuming the `foreign_key` is indexed) is also a BTree, but the leaf node contains a copy pf the `PRIMARY KEY` for the row it finds.  Then a second lookup is performed to get to the data (including `some_column`).

Based on that logic, a secondary key lookup takes about twice as long as lookup by the PK.  However, since there is a lot of other stuff going on in any `SELECT`, so you will rarely measure 2x.

There are other issues...

If `some_column` is one of the columns in the PK, then your second `SELECT` acts like the first.

If you have `INDEX(foreign_key, some_column)`, then this will be faster because the task will be finished after drilling down this key's BTree.  That is, there is no need for the second probe with the PK.

If the test in the `WHERE` does not involve an index, then a "table scan" is performed.  For a thousand-row table, the query will take a thousand times as long.  (Actually it is not that much difference, again due to overhead.)  Anyway, a thousand rows can be scanned in a few milliseconds, so a missing index on a 'tiny' table is *usually* not a big deal.

That is a few tidbits of the dozens, maybe hundreds, of subtle things that go on with indexes and Optimization.

More, but not all, tidbits are found [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .